# Install Sump Pump Check Valve on Washing Machine

Tags: plumbing, repair, water, laundry

We just purchased a Everbuilt THD1020 (In-Line Sump Pump Check Valve) , and installed in the back hose of our washing machine. The original hose would leak detergent soap and water. Is it a good practice to install In-Line check valves like this on washing machines? Are there any negative consequences, issues with flooding or clogging from doing this? The original hose kept leaking, so decide to get this instead. How does this fit in state california rules?

[image]

[image]

https://www.homedepot.com/p/Everbilt-1-25-in-and-1-5-in-ABS-In-Line-Sump-Pump-Check-Valve-THD1020/205616001

Update: Reading the website from **Home Depot**, trying to understand, see if it applies to my situation

"Can you use this on a 2inch waste line every time washing machine drains it flows back up through the tub drain"

Answers "That's probably not the best way to resolve your problem but it may be the only way without knowing more about your situation. If you do decide to use this, and if it is at all possible, mount this check valve in the horizontal position. The reason for this is that unlike sump pumps that usually eject clear water, washing machines are continually ejecting water mixed with particulate. If the valve was mounted in the vertical position, particulate could get lodged in the valve easier and could cause it not to seal all the way. If mounting it horizontally is not possible, then you could go ahead and try it vertically. The worst thing that could happen is that the valve could temporarily get stuck open and you end up right back to where you are today."

"you could, understanding some limitations. tub drain will allow hair and other crud through it so check valve might eventually not offer full seal against reverse wash as it accumulates this debris. key is to have a screen or strainer in your tub drain to eliminate this from going down in first place. However, you probably need to solve the underlying problem of the slow drain which empties the washer and tub. Try some digestive enzymes such as Roebic RBC to open that common drainpipe. Or manually clean it out with an auger."

Comment: TLDR. You should not need a water-tight connection between your washing machine drain hose and the pipe that it drains into (which is usually a standpipe of some sort, to hold *some* of the water while it has time to drain). You have a drain obstruction (or undersized drain) and a check valve will not help. Snake the line then open the wall and build a bigger standpipe...

Comment: I agree with jimmy if you have water backing up your drain line is partially plugged or under sized. I would fix the problem back pressure on the washer pump may cause it to fail

Comment: someone is free to post an answer, and I can send points

Answer (score 2):

If you have water backing up your drain line is partially plugged or under sized. I would fix the problem back pressure on the washer pump may cause it to fail much sooner than normal. If the line is backing up it would be advisable to run a snake down the line to clear it out. Many homes have a clean out close to washers but not all. Snaking the line would be my first thing to attempt.

Comment: do you think adding a sump pump check valve would make problem worse? thats what I originally asked in the question , thanks !

Comment: It may cause damage to your pump or shorten its life. I don’t think it would make things worse as far as the drain issue ic concerned.